# aggregate function help in sql?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

If I have the following data:

```
Policy Number:       Amount:
100                    200
100                    100
101                    50 
102                    90
```

What can I write in SQL code to get the following result without changing the data

```
Policy Number:    Amount:
100                 300
101                 50
102                 90
```

Comment: Asking for help at the bottom of your questions is unnecessary, it also takes up valuable screen real estate. It is assumed you need help if you post a question. You can simply show appreciation for the assistance by upvoting answers that are useful, and accepting correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select policy_number, sum(amount) as amount
from table_name
group by policy_number
order by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to group-by the non-aggregated column like so:

```
select 
  [Policy Number], 
  sum(Amount)
from the_table
  group by [Policy Number]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PolicyNumber, SUM(Amount) FROM Table GROUP BY PolicyNumber
```